# Missing likes field of a page at graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

i am trying to obtain how much likes one of my pages has, and only this one page isn't showing the likes field, even having about 1 thousand likes, check it out:

https://graph.facebook.com/233572770052788?fields=likes

```
{
  "id": "233572770052788", 
  "type": "page"
}
```

This one, responds just fine:
https://graph.facebook.com/173268742773034?fields=likes

```
{
  "likes": 348, 
  "id": "173268742773034", 
  "type": "page"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) for your non-facebook page.

Then you may retrieve number of likes as follows:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select total_count from link_stat where url='http://tvg.globo.com/bbb/bbb12/videos/t/agora-na-casa/v/monique-tira-a-roupa-e-faz-a-alegria-da-casa/1762991/'
```

[Try here](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20total_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27http://tvg.globo.com/bbb/bbb12/videos/t/agora-na-casa/v/monique-tira-a-roupa-e-faz-a-alegria-da-casa/1762991/%27)

It uses following FQL Query: `select total_count from link_stat where url='yourUrl'`

Comment: this page has over nine hundred (900) likes.

Comment: copy the url and paste it at the like button social plugin( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ ), its over 1 thousand now, as its the most popular video on my website.

Comment: Thanks rudolf, but i should be able to get that using graph, dont you agree? Its good to know that there is another way to retrieve the information, but i realy need it working at the graph api.

Comment: OK - please let me know how did you get the id:233572770052788. Because page registered by facebook at that id really has 0 likes. (please note that even like button you are using gives different results for url with "/" at the end and without it)

Comment: Try this one: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=http%3A%2F%2Ftvg.globo.com%2Fbbb%2Fbbb12%2Fvideos%2Ft%2Fagora-na-casa%2Fv%2Fmonique-tira-a-roupa-e-faz-a-alegria-da-casa%2F1762991%2F

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a bug at facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Facebook is full of bugs: http://www.quora.com/Is-it-true-that-Facebook-has-no-testers